# PHP not able to compile

Tags: compiler-errors

recently encountered a problem,

I used to run PHP codes earlier, no problems arised.

But now all of a sudden the code doesn't compile,

A simple code as

```
<?php
 echo 'Test';
?>
```

returns the whole code on the webpage itself. No output, just the whole code. It fails to recognise php.

Note - I have Apache and MySQL switched on in XAMPP
and the html code runs successfully in a php file.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: PHP code *never* compiles - it's interpreted ....

Comment: Yes, my bad. My point is what i see as the output is  "the code" i had written in my notepad